# How to stop people talking to you while using the bathroom

Tags: awkward-situations, acquaintances

It seems that there are a certain group of people who would like to chat with you, whilst you are using the bathroom.

It can feel quite invasive and just down right awkward.

Responses, in general, seem out of the question over pure silence.

How can I get people to stop talking to me while I’m using the bathroom?

Comment: *a certain group of people*... who are? family? friends? coworkers? I would definately **not** answer to these people the same way...

Comment: @OldPadawan Probably more like extroverts?

Comment: be them introverted or extroverted person, I still think that family/friends/coworkers should not be answered the same way :) and that maybe that information is important.

Comment: Just for clarity here - the people you are referring to are *always* your acquiescence or can they also be strangers?

Comment: Drop a very loud fart. They will stop, believe me.

Answer (score 6):

I say something on the lines of "Hey, let me come out of this stall and then we'll talk". If someone asks me why, I tell them I find it odd to talk that way and they don't bother me any longer. I had a colleague who used to have all kinds of phone conversations from bathroom - she'd talk to her family, friends, even give interviews while on the toilet seat. I used to find that gross but I guess, to each their own. So if you don't like it, just ask them to wait till you come out of the bathroom - most people understand.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same thing in the past. I felt very uncomfortable when someone tried to talk to me while using the bathroom. 
The solution I hit upon was to not reply. Let them talk all they want - you can't stop someone from talking - but you are in no way obliged to respond. If the people in question have a problem with that, well, it's their problem. If afterwards they query you over your silence, there is the opportunity to explain how uncomfortable it makes you feel.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe turn the tables on them ..."ahhhh that one felt goooood"... most outside talkers would feel offended/invaded, and that is good, since they will exactly understand you now.

You need a plan B, though, if you find out that there are people among the talkers that ARE genuinely more open about these matters than what suits your tastes.

Comment: "Ah dinnae have any corn!"